# PIC18F4550 + 16x2 LCD code query

Tags: microcontroller, lcd

I'm a beginner in MCU programming and also very eager to learn lots about it. Recently I have acquired the "Aptinex development board rev.6" which has many features already attached. I also bought a PIC18F4550 to plug it in the board. I've managed to understand how the basics of I/O operations work, but now I have stumbled on the LCD, which is attached to the development board. I found the code bellow in one of many tutorials pages all over google, and decided to try it out because it seemed simple enough. The code works without problems.

```
//File name 'LCD_Display_String_Original.c'
#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000
#define RS LATD0
#define EN LATD1
#define D4 LATD2
#define D5 LATD3
#define D6 LATD4
#define D7 LATD5

#include <xc.h>
#include "lcd.h"

void delay_ms(unsigned int delay_value)
{
while(delay_value-- > 0)
// While desired delay value is more than 0, decrement that value by 1 after each 10ms
{
    __delay_ms(1);
    // Wait 10ms
}                       
}

int main()
{
TRISD = 0b00000000;
Lcd_Init();
while(1)
{
    Lcd_Clear();
    Lcd_Set_Cursor(1,1);
    Lcd_Write_String("Hello world!");
    delay_ms(1000);

}
}
```

The question that I have is, could someone kindly please explain what is going on in the function **Lcd_port (char a);**, located in the lcd.h file bellow. Can't understand what conditions are tested and how they are true or false.

```
//File name 'lcd.h'
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void Lcd_Port(char a)
{
if(a & 1)
    D4 = 1;
else
    D4 = 0;

if(a & 2)
    D5 = 1;
else
    D5 = 0;

if(a & 4)
    D6 = 1;
else
    D6 = 0;

if(a & 8)
    D7 = 1;
else
    D7 = 0;
}

void Lcd_Cmd(char a)
{
RS = 0;             // => RS = 0
Lcd_Port(a);
EN  = 1;             // => E = 1
    __delay_ms(4);
    EN  = 0;             // => E = 0
}

Lcd_Clear()
{
Lcd_Cmd(0);
Lcd_Cmd(1);
}

void Lcd_Set_Cursor(char a, char b)
{
char temp,z,y;
if(a == 1)
{
  temp = 0x80 + b - 1;
    z = temp>>4;
    y = temp & 0x0F;
    Lcd_Cmd(z);
    Lcd_Cmd(y);
}
else if(a == 2)
{
    temp = 0xC0 + b - 1;
    z = temp>>4;
    y = temp & 0x0F;
    Lcd_Cmd(z);
    Lcd_Cmd(y);
}
}

void Lcd_Init()
{
Lcd_Port(0x00);
__delay_ms(20);
Lcd_Cmd(0x03);
__delay_ms(5);
Lcd_Cmd(0x03);
__delay_ms(11);
Lcd_Cmd(0x03);

Lcd_Cmd(0x02);
Lcd_Cmd(0x02);
Lcd_Cmd(0x08);
Lcd_Cmd(0x00);
Lcd_Cmd(0x0C);
Lcd_Cmd(0x00);
Lcd_Cmd(0x06);
}

void Lcd_Write_Char(char a)
{
char temp,y;
temp = a&0x0F;
y = a&0xF0;
RS = 1;             // => RS = 1
Lcd_Port(y>>4);             //Data transfer
EN = 1;
__delay_us(40);
EN = 0;
Lcd_Port(temp);
EN = 1;
__delay_us(40);
EN = 0;
}

void Lcd_Write_String(char *a)
{
int i;
for(i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++)
   Lcd_Write_Char(a[i]);
}

void Lcd_Shift_Right()
{
Lcd_Cmd(0x01);
Lcd_Cmd(0x0C);
}

void Lcd_Shift_Left()
{
Lcd_Cmd(0x01);
Lcd_Cmd(0x08);
}
```

As mentioned before, the code works perfectly fine. I just really need someone to explain how that part works. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this would be a much better fit on electronics.SE (I've also flagged it for moderator attention because they can probably move it to a site which isn't listed in the default options).

Comment: Are you asking how the [Bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operator works?

Comment: The function `Lcd_Port` is examining each of 4 bits of `a` and transferring their value to outputs (either 0 or 1). `if(a & 1)` is shorthand for `if((a & 1) != 0)`

Comment: To add to the above comment, the reason it's done this way is because the pins used for the LCD can be easily remapped.  They do not have to be part of the same actual memory byte.  They can also be in different order from their natural byte order.  This allows flexibility in moving these pins to other MCU pins with minimal code changes; only the pin definitions need to be changed.

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers. I think I almost got it, just need a bit more clarity. So lets say:
1. Lcd_Port() receives a value of 'a' = '0x03' from the Lcd_Cmd() function, binary 0b0011
2. Decimal '1' is 0b0001
3. After the logical AND operation the result is 0b0001, which makes the condition TRUE, because it is more than zero, as mentioned above by Weather Vane, thus setting the corresponding pin D4 high. 

And in this case, if 'a' was 0b1100, the condition would be false then, because 0b1100 AND 0b0001 would produce 0b0000, thus setting the pin D4 low. Is this the correct?

Comment: @GiedriusElectrum yes that is correct. But rather than say "more than zero" it is better to say "not equal to zero". It's a fine distinction but values can be signed, so could (in the general case) actually be "less than zero". Note too that `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...` are decimal values representing a single `1` bit in successive bit positions, masking off a single bit in the operand.

Comment: @Weather Vane, thank you! Still, there a couple of things that confuse me. In my understanding, and please correct me if I'm wrong, when working with the LCD in 4-bit mode, the data is first sent bit by bit (Bit8 > Bit7 > Bit6 > Bit5) or in our case (0>0>1>1) in 4-bit higher nibble (D7-MSB,D6,D5,D4-LSB) while masking (ignoring) the lower 4-bit nibble (D3-MSB, D2, D1, D0-LSB), and then sending the lower 4-bit nibble while masking the higher 4-bit nibble.

Comment: @Weather Vane, to add - What confuses me the most, is how are we masking those nibbles exactly? How are we influencing the bits that are not even connected to the MCU (D3,D2,D1 and D0). Also, I am not so sure if I'm right about the bits 8-4 and 5-1 being MSB and LSB, respectively. 
I hope my questions are clear. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: There are numerous type of LCD controller. In your case it looks as if you are writing 4 bits to the output, then strobing the `E` line to "latch" these data bits to the device. The LCD will accept 4 bits of information at a time. You set these bits up on the output port bits, then you go "click here you are, the data is ready". BTW the bits are numbered 7-4 and 3-0.